# Can NDS-11 300 V relay socket be replaced with NDS-11 600 V?

Tags: relay, socket

In short, I’m trying to fix an evaporator fan that locked up on a freezer and have no experience with electrical components. The NDS11 relay (300 V) has some rusted screws that won’t break loose so it also needed to be replaced. The new one came and it's 600 V while the original is 300 V.

Can I use the 600 V without issue or do I need to buy a new 300 V relay?

Answer (score 0):

Relays and switches generally provide *contact* ratings which tell you what they can safely handle and interrupt. They will sometimes provide both an AC and a DC figure. Because AC has a zero-crossing, usually the voltage rating will be higher for AC.

If the new relay has a higher voltage rating for its contacts than the old one, congratulations, it is a more robust relay! You can safely use it. Just be certain that you are not mixing up DC vs AC ratings (e.g. looking at the DC rating on the old one and the AC rating on the new one).

Comment: Thank you for your response!!

Comment: @BTBott You are welcome, please be sure to check out https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers